# SXA search filters don't intersect itself

Tags: sxa, content-search, search-facet

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I have checklist filter with data as seen:
[image]

Individual has items : News3, News4, News7
[image]

Vacation has items : News3, News5, News6
[image]

When I choose these two options, it's supposed to get me the common item which is News3, but this is not the case as it get all the data of the options(Union not Intersection)
[image]

Is there is any OOB solution for this.

Comment: I don't think there is an ootb solution for this.

Comment: So, how can I fix it, I've tried to decompile the search service dll to override the current implementation but couldn't understand it.